# ¿Cuál sería el término correcto para referirse a uno/a mismo/a utilizando el verbo "decir"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, imperativo, verbo-pronominal

Me gustaría saber qué término utilizar de manera correcta.
En algunos blogs se debate entre "di a ti mismo/a" y "dite a ti mismo/a" pero no sé cuál sería más correcto, ni si existe alguna manera de expresarlo mejor.

Comment: Se puede decir "Evaluarme a mi mismo"

Comment: Sadly my proposal was deleted, so I'll have to contribute via a comment.  It is awkward no matter how you approach it.  Workaround: *Habla contigo mismo/misma. Di, "Tú mereces mejor."*  (The reflexive pronoun isn't needed with "Di" as long as the context sets things up clearly.)

Answer (score 6):

En su análisis de las distintas funciones del pronombre “se” (que puede hacerse extensivo a los pronombres átonos “me”, “te”, “nos”, “os”), el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs) dice:

> b) Pronombre personal de tercera persona con valor reflexivo (el sujeto realiza la acción, o la manda realizar, sobre sí mismo) o recíproco (la acción la realizan varios individuos, los unos sobre los otros). En ambos casos el pronombre *se* puede desempeñar funciones de complemento directo o indirecto: *María se peina* (complemento directo reflexivo); *María se lava las manos* (complemento indirecto reflexivo); *Los novios se conocieron en un viaje* (complemento directo recíproco); *Ana y Luis se escriben cartas de amor* (complemento indirecto recíproco). En el uso reflexivo, puede añadirse el refuerzo tónico *a sí mismo*, siempre que sea el sujeto quien efectivamente realice la acción: *Se convenció a sí mismo de que podía ganar*, frente a *Se convenció* [gracias a los argumentos de otros] *de que podía ganar*. Hay verbos que admiten el uso conjunto del *se* reflexivo en función de complemento directo y del prefijo de sentido reflexivo *auto-*.

Como podemos leer arriba, “en el uso reflexivo, **puede añadirse** el refuerzo tónico *a sí mismo*”. Esto significa que la frase “a mí/ti/nosotros/ustedes/vosotros mismos” no funciona en forma independiente, sino reforzando al pronombre átono:

- Míra**te (a ti mismo)**.
- Observémo**nos (a nosotros mismos)**.

Por lo tanto, la forma correcta sería:

- Di**te (a ti mismo)**...

Ahora bien, el verbo “decir” requiere un complemento directo, y por lo tanto debe haber uno presente para que la oración sea correcta:

- Dite a ti mismo que eres el mejor.

En el caso particular del verbo “decir” en imperativo, la oración es estilísticamente superior con el refuerzo tónico “a ti mismo”. Esto, me parece, se debe a que los verbos de decir (excepto “preguntarse”) comúnmente llevan un complemento indirecto diferente del sujeto.

Si no, tal vez debamos elegir otra opción, por ejemplo:

- Convéncete de que eres el mejor.

Answer (score 4):

La forma más correcta es la segunda.

"Dite a ti misma·.

El complemento indirecto puedes especificarlo o no, pero el pronombre siempre debe aparecer. Ocurre lo mismo con "Me dijo a mí". Puedes decir simplemente "Me dijo" o "dite", puedes especificar más, pero el pronombre es necesario.

[Aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF) la página de la RAE donde se explica:

> 5. Duplicación de complementos: coaparición del clítico y el complemento tónico. En español, los pronombres átonos aparecen a
>      menudo dentro de la misma oración junto con el complemento tónico al
>      que se refieren: *Me dijo a mí que me callara*; *Lo sabe todo*. La
>      duplicación del complemento indirecto a través del pronombre átono es
>      siempre posible y, en algunos casos, obligatoria, mientras que la del
>      complemento directo está sujeta a muchas más restricciones. En el
>      español general culto la coaparición del pronombre átono y el
>      complemento tónico responde a las pautas siguientes:
>
> 5.1. **Si el complemento tónico es también un pronombre personal, la coaparición del pronombre átono es obligatoria**, tanto si el
>   complemento es directo como indirecto [...]

Answer (score 0):

Propongo el pronominal en segunda persona en forma enclítica "Dítelo".

El cual puede ser conjugado con los otros pronombres

- Te
- Me
- Se
- Nos

Aunque pueda sonar a pleonasmo: **dítelo a ti mismo** considero que es un uso correcto para dar énfasis como en los casos : **dímelo a mi** o **díselo a el/ellos**

[Lo que tiene que decir la rae de los enclíticos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF)

> Pronombres personales átonos. 1. Formas. Los pronombres personales átonos son aquellos que funcionan como complemento verbal no preposicional (Ya te lo he dicho) o como formante de los verbos pronominales (Ahora me arrepiento). Precisamente por su carácter átono, se pronuncian necesariamente ligados al verbo, con el que forman una unidad acentual. Estos pronombres carentes de independencia fónica se denominan, en general, «clíticos» (→ acento, 1.1b): cuando anteceden al verbo (me encanta; lo dijo; se fue) se llaman «proclíticos»; cuando siguen al verbo (ayúdame, díselo, vete) se llaman «**enclíticos**».

[Lo que dice wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Pronombre_encl%C3%ADtico)

> El pronombre enclítico es el que se une al verbo precedente para formar una sola palabra:
>
> > aparta + se + lo > apártaselo
>
> Todos los pronombres pospuestos van unidos al verbo.